# Module parse failed: Unexpected token Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Module parse failed: Unexpected token Reactjs?

ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| ReactDOM.render(

> ```
> <App />,
> ```

|     document.getElementById('app')
| );

@ multi ./src/index.js main[0]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.jsx'
    ],
    output:{
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
          { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
          { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried renaming it to `index.jsx`?

Comment: ERROR in ./src/index.jsx 6:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Comment: | ReactDOM.render(
>     <App />,
|     document.getElementById('app')
| );
 @ multi ./src/index.jsx main[0]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: post your webpack config

Comment: module.exports = {
 entry: [
  './src/index.jsx'
 ],
 output:{
  path: __dirname,
  filename: 'app/js/main.js'
 },
 module:{
  rules: [
       { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
       { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
     ]
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

The message is quite clear that you haven't setup the loader to transpile your `jsx` file yet. Your config file doesn't cover for `jsx?` file but you did for `ts` file. The solution is just either add `babel` + `babel-loader` to your project or switch file to `ts` format would resolve your issue.

Here is the basic steps if you go for babel anyway:

Install packages needed:

```
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader
```

Add babel loader to webpack config:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          "@babel/env",
          "@babel/react"
        ]
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (G:\new-react\reactquiz\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:40:36)
 @ multi ./src/index.jsx main[0]

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (G:\new-react\reactquiz\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:40:36)

Comment: @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.jsx main[0]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: seems I missed `babel-cli` I edited the answer again. Please check it out

Comment: [./src/index.jsx] 239 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 239 bytes {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

Comment: ERROR in ./src/index.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (G:\new-react\reactquiz\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:40:36)
 @ multi ./src/index.jsx main[0]

Comment: ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'babel' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports (G:\new-react\reactquiz\node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:40:36)
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.jsx main[0]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: you might have to check your `babel-loader` version since I don't see any index file at the root level of the latest version as this is saying `node_modules\babel-loader\index.js:40: `. I think it's best to use the latest version all of above packages.

Comment: how to user latest version pls help me?

Comment: i am new in react

Comment: You just simply re-install as same as my above command which will automatically install the latest version for you

Comment: and how to use config js ? and which command using me

Comment: sorry but I don't know what did you mean :| can I see your package.json file?

Comment: {
  "name": "reactquiz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple Quiz app in react",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Pankaj Upadhyay",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-core": "5.8.*",
    "babel-loader": "^5.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.7",

Comment: "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  }
}

Comment: I think a part from babel-loader, you should also update webpack as well. Now you can run the following script: `npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react babel-loader webpack`. Then check if any changes are made at this file